# No module named django.core

Tags: django

Добрый день. Пытаюсь запустить Python Django под Windows. Python 3.5.2

Создал виртуальное окружение, в обычном cmd активирую его:

```
Scripts\activate.bat
```

Активировалось успешно. Запускаю команду

```
django-admin.py startproject dj
```

На что получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "...\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module> from django.core import management
Import error: No module named django.core
```

Django совершенно точно установлен, я его вижу в проекте Lib\site-packages\django. Прописал в переменную среды PATH пути Lib, Scripts, Lib\site-packages, Lib\site-packages\django. Также пробовал

```
import sys
sys.path.append("...\\dj")
sys.path.append("...\\dj\\site-packages")
```

Comment: Внутри виртуального окружения Django-то не забыли установить?

Comment: Внутри окружения установлен.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй использовать команду : - `django-admin.exe startproject dj .`

---

Так как ты используешь Windows, то твоя команда должна содержать .exe

p.s Точка в конце обязательно.

Comment: Нет, Python-скрипты никогда не могут содержать `exe` в конце. Даже в Windows.